# Hacer resgistro y login personalizado en WordPress

Tags: php, html, wordpress

Como puedo crear un *template* para registro de usuarios y *login* que no sea la de WordPress propiamente?

Es decir, de momento tengo un `custom-login.php` donde se compone de una caja dividida en dos, uno es para el *login* (que eso esta resuelto) y el otro es para el registro de usuarios. Aquí viene el problema, no se como crear un formulario de registro que interactúe directamente con el sistema de WordPress y registre a los usuarios.

He creado un modulo propio asi:

```
<?php
$password       = isset( $_POST['password'] ) ? $_POST['password'] : null;
$password_check = isset( $_POST['password_check'] ) ? $_POST['password_check'] : null;
$useremail      = isset( $_POST['email'] ) ? $_POST['email'] : null;
$terms          = isset( $_POST['terms'] ) ? $_POST['terms'] : null;

echo $password . $password_check . $useremail . $terms;
define( 'WP_USE_THEMES', false );
$parse_uri = explode( 'wp-content', $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'] );
require_once( $parse_uri[0] . 'wp-load.php' );

global $reg_errors;
$reg_errors = new WP_Error;

if ( empty( $useremail ) || empty( $password ) ) {
    $reg_errors->add( 'field', 'Bitte fülle alle notwendigen Eingabefeler aus' );
}

if ( ! is_email( $useremail ) ) {
    $reg_errors->add( 'email_invalid', 'Email-Adresse ist ungültig' );
}

if ( $password_check != $password ) {
    $reg_errors->add( 'password', 'Passwörter stimmen nicht überein' );
}

if ( email_exists( $useremail ) ) {
    $reg_errors->add( 'email', 'Die E-Mail Adresse wird schon genutzt!' );
}

if ( 5 > strlen( $password ) ) {
    $reg_errors->add( 'password', 'Das Passwort braucht mindestens 5 Zeichen' );
}

if ( ! isset( $_POST['terms'] ) ) {
    $reg_errors->add( 'terms', "Bitte akzeptiere die Bedingungen" );
}

if ( is_wp_error( $reg_errors ) ) {
    foreach ( $reg_errors->get_error_messages() as $error ) {
        echo '<div>';
        echo '<strong>ERROR</strong>:';
        echo $error . '<br/>';
        echo '</div>';
    }

    if ( 1 > count( $reg_errors->get_error_messages() ) ) {
        $userdata = array(
            'user_login' => $useremail,
            'user_email' => $useremail,
            'user_pass'  => $password,
            'role'       => 'Arbeitnehmer'
        );
        $user     = wp_insert_user( $userdata );
        echo "Erfolgreich registriert!";
    }
}
```

Y luego en el lugar donde aparece este modulo debe funcionar esta asi:

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri() ?>/register_handler/register_normal_user.php"  id="registrieren-form">
                <div class="row boxes"> 
                    <!--<label for="email">E-Mail</label>-->
                    <input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="E-MAIL">
                    <!--<label for="password">Passwort</label>-->
                    <input type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="PASSWORT">
                    <!--<label for="password_check">Passwort wiederholen</label>-->
                    <input type="password" name="password_check" id="password_check" placeholder="Passwort wiederholen">
                </div>
                <div class="row terms" >
                    <label for="terms"><?php echo $registerbox['terms']; ?></label>
                    <input name="terms" id="terms" type="checkbox" value="Yes">
                </div>   
                <div class="row">

                    <input type="submit" id="signin" name="submit" value="Registieren"/>

                </div>

            </form>
```

Las rutas donde se llama el post es correcta

**ACTUALIZACIÓN:**

Había un fallo en una de las lineas de un punto y como y por eso no hacia el registro.

Despues de varias horas, ya esta solucionado. Ahora solo queda integrar los errores que he visto que sde hacen con javascript, pero me tengo que informar mejor de eso a ver.

Comment: Podrías mostrarnos cómo lo estás intentando. Así como está planteada, nos estás pidiendo que implementemos una solución desde cero

Comment: Es que no tengo nada hecho por que no se por donde empezar, loq ue quiero no es que nadie lo implemente, quiero hacerlo yo, pero no se como llamar el sistema de registro de wordpress e inplementarlo a mi manera. Ese es el problema, solo encuetro o como desarrollar un plugin o como usar ya un plugin creado.

Comment: Aquí puedes ver un ejemplo: http://www.wpbeginner.com/plugins/how-to-create-a-custom-user-registration-form-in-wordpress/ hay muchas más formas, si no te vale puedes intentar crear un módulo propio en PHP

Comment: Gracias, he optado por crear un modulo propio, pero no logro que los input funcionen correctamente. Vpy a proceder arriba a adjuntar mi codigo